# bukkit runnable IllegalStateException

Tags: java, minecraft, illegalstateexception

guys Im making a spigot 1.8 plugin. it worked on 1.16 but in 1.8 it throws this:

```
[10:00:59 ERROR]: Could not pass event InventoryClickEvent to Knockback_PVP v1.0.0
.....
org.bukkit.event.EventException
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already scheduled as 1201
        at org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable.checkState(BukkitRunnable.java:141) ~[spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable.runTask(BukkitRunnable.java:31) ~[spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
...
```

here is a part of my code:

```
BukkitRunnable runnable = new BukkitRunnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (plugin.RegenTasks.containsKey(getTaskId()) == false) return;
                Player p = plugin.RegenTasks.get(getTaskId());
                p.getInventory().setItem(3, new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND));
                plugin.RegenTasks.remove(getTaskId());
                return;
            }
        };
        runnable.runTaskLater(plugin, 2*20*30);
        plugin.RegenTasks.put(runnable.getTaskId(),p);
```

and in somewhere else when the player dies:

```
if (plugin.RegenTasks.containsValue(p)){ 
    for (int i: plugin.RegenTasks.keySet()) {
        if (plugin.RegenTasks.get(i) == p) {
            plugin.RegenTasks.remove(i);
                try 
                    {plugin.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTask(i);}
                finally {break;}
        }
    }
}
```

any way to fix it?

Comment: What line of your code ist causing this Exeption?

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule a BukkitRunnable only once. Also your error message tells you that.

> Already scheduled as 1201

Take a look at Javadoc:

[IllegalStateException - if this was already scheduled](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitRunnable.html)

So either call the runnable only once or schedule your task e.g. like this:

[`BukkitScheduler.scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(...)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitScheduler.html#scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin,org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable,long,long))

Comment: I know what is that error but Im confused because I've never runned it more than once